# need to click twice for jquery submit

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$.validator.setDefaults({
    submitHandler: function () {
        $('#search').submit(function () {
            var city = $("#city").val();
            var adults = $("#adults").val();
            var children = $("#children").val();
            var SDate = $("#hotelStartDate").val();
            var EDate = $("#hotelEndDate").val();
            SDate = SDate.substr(6, 4) + '-' + SDate.substr(3, 2) + '-' + SDate.substr(0, 2);
            EDate = EDate.substr(6, 4) + '-' + EDate.substr(3, 2) + '-' + EDate.substr(0, 2);
            jQuery(":submit", this).css("display", "none");
            jQuery(":submit", this).after("<span class='button nice awesome green large radius'>Searching...</span>");
            location.href = 'http://www.dhitrax.com/destination.php?checkin=' + SDate + '&checkout=' + EDate + '&city=' + city + '&adults=' + adults + '&children=' + children;
            return false;
        });
    },
    highlight: function (input) {
        $(input).addClass("ui-state-highlight");
    },
    unhighlight: function (input) {
        $(input).removeClass("ui-state-highlight");
    }
});
$().ready(function () {
    $.fn.themeswitcher && $('<div/>').css({
        position: "absolute",
        right: 10,
        top: 10
    }).appendTo(document.body).themeswitcher();
    $("#search").validate({
        rules: {
            city: "required",
            hotelStartDate: "required",
            hotelEndDate: "required"
        },
        messages: {
            City: "Please type your destination",
            hotelStartDate: "Select check in Date",
            hotelEndDate: "Select check out Date"
        }
    });
});
});
```

Comment: WTH..add it into jsfiddle..

Comment: you are supposed to format your code properly

Comment: what problem/error are you facing .. this code  doesnt very helpful to answer

Comment: You will get a better response if you explain what you have tried and what you have already attempted. You should also give a detailed explanation of your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't bind an event handler to the `submit` event *inside* of the existing `submitHandler` jQuery validate provides. It's taking two clicks to submit the form because the first time you submit, the handler is bound and the second time you submit the handler is executed.

This should be as simple as moving your code into the `submitHandler`:

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    submitHandler: function () {
        var city = $("#city").val();
        var adults = $("#adults").val();
        var children = $("#children").val();
        var SDate = $("#hotelStartDate").val();
        var EDate = $("#hotelEndDate").val();
        SDate = SDate.substr(6, 4) + '-' + SDate.substr(3, 2) + '-' + SDate.substr(0, 2);
        EDate = EDate.substr(6, 4) + '-' + EDate.substr(3, 2) + '-' + EDate.substr(0, 2);
        jQuery(":submit", this).css("display", "none");
        jQuery(":submit", this).after("<span class='button nice awesome green large radius'>Searching...</span>");
        location.href = 'http://www.dhitrax.com/destination.php?checkin=' + SDate + '&checkout=' + EDate + '&city=' + city + '&adults=' + adults + '&children=' + children;
    },
    highlight: function (input) {
        $(input).addClass("ui-state-highlight");
    },
    unhighlight: function (input) {
        $(input).removeClass("ui-state-highlight");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew, but it doesn't show searching button.please help me as i am newbie

Comment: Hard to say why without seeing your markup. Also the page is redirecting immediately so could it be that the next page is loading so fast that you can't see it?